# Why is Spacetime described as flat even though we live in 3 dimensions of space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, spacetime-dimensions, visualization

I’ve always heard and seen diagrams  that show spacetime as being “flat” or in 2 dimensions with curvature. How does this correspond to the 3 spacial dimensions that we perceive to exist in?

Comment: Note that you seem to be asking about space (3D) and not spacetime (4D).

Comment: @Sten: That's certainly how one of the answerers addressed the question, but in writing my own answer I was not so sure about the OP's intention.

Comment: How could any 2D diagram show anywhere as anything but 'flat' or in two dimensions?

Comment: Flat does not mean 2D. Speaking purely math, space appears flat to a hypothetical 4D observer in the same way as a 2D piece of paper appears flat to you as a 3D observer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

"Flat space" means that on large scales, Euclidean geometry holds.  All the angles in any triangle drawn in space add up to 180°; the total distance between points separated by $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, and $\Delta z$ is $d=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2}$; et cetera.

Note that this is *not* the case on the 2D surface of the Earth, because it is curved.  If you have a globe or a basketball to play with, you can easily see that it's possible to draw a triangle with more than 180°.  You can even draw one with three 90° angles for a total of 270°.  On a sphere, the distance between two nearby points is $ds = \sqrt{dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2sin^2\theta d\phi^2}$ where $(\theta,\phi)$ are the longitude and latitude.  In general, Euclidian geometry does not apply.

The statement that in our universe, space is flat, means that on the largest scales (disregarding curvature "wrinkles" caused by stars, galaxies, black holes, etc) our 3D universe is measured to be flat such that Euclidean geometry applies.  This also implies that it could be infinite in extent.  If it were positively curved like a (3D) spherical surface, it might wrap in on itself and be finite in extent.  The picture is somewhat analogous a smooth metallic surface.  Although under a microscope you can see the surface roughness and all kinds of asperities, hills, and valleys, zooming out to a macroscopic view the overall structure is smooth and flat.

Comment: How is surface of earth is 2D ? Suppose the centre of earth as origin, then we need three coordinates to specify any point of surface.

Comment: @An_Elephant you don't need three coordinates, because the radius is the same  at every point on the earth's surface.

Comment: @An_Elephant you just need latitude and longitude to specify any position on earth's surface.

Comment: @AbhirupMukherjee Then still , you'll need three numbers, the $x,y$ and $R$. Even though $R$ is constant.

Comment: @justhalf Wish if I knew some geography 

Comment: @An_Elephant Take the Earth's surface as given then you need just latitude and longitude. R is a given constant. It describes the curvature of the surface but latitude and longitude can be used by themselves (without R) to specify a point on the surface.

Comment: @An_Elephant One way to think of the surface of a sphere as 2D is this: given any two of three 3D cartesian coordinates for a point on the surface of the sphere, the third coordinate can be solved for ($x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$). In other words, there are only 2 independent variables. This property is independent of coordinate system, so the surface of a sphere is said to be 2D.

Comment: As a slight nitpick the universe being flat doesn't really imply that it is infinite in extent. It is perfectly possible to have a compact manifold which has a flat metric. The classic example would probably be the flat tourus, although an even simpler example is a circle (with the usual metric). (I don't know enough about cosmology to say whether there is any evidence about if the universe is bounded, this is just a mathematical perspective).

Comment: @Vaelus Thanks , but isn't radius independent of all the coordinates and hence it's still 3 numbers needed to specify position , even though one of the numbers is fixed.

Comment: No. Fixing one coordinate in 3D space defines a 2D surface, e.g. defining $x=2$ defines a plane in $y, z$

Comment: @Fishbane, good point. I think a cylinder is another (2D) example of a finite flat surface.

Comment: @An_Elephant Good observation. When describing any point in 3D space, radius is indeed variable, so of x, y, z, and r (radius), you must know any three to derive the fourth, implying 3 independent variables and 3 dimensions. However, on just the surface of a sphere, radius is constant. It's value is know just by virtue of having chosen a sphere to talk about. It's value doesn't vary independently of the other coordinates, because it doesn't vary at all. As long as everyone agrees about which sphere they're talking about, you only need to give two coordinates to identify a point on its surface.

Comment: @Vaelus Oh thanks now I finally get it. Having a radius means having a sphere to talk about.

Comment: If you draw a triangle in a basketball, you're not drawing straight lines. Euclidean geometry allows such curved triangles to have any internal angles without being violated

Comment: @Juan, if you read Euclid's 5 postulates, you'll see that majority do not apply on the surface of a sphere. You bring up a good point, and Bernhard Riemann came up with a very particular set of rules to define locally what "straight" means, and how curvature is measured. E.g. parallel transport.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidsPostulates.html

Comment: @An_Elephant Longitude and Latitude. You don't need R. You know R if you can observe the globe. If someone asks you where you house is, long/lat, you don't give the height, because houses are on the surface of earth.

Answer (score 11):

The meaning of "flat" here is not the colloquial meaning, and it certainly does not mean "in 2 dimensions with curvature".

Instead, the meaning of "flat" here is the mathematical meaning: there is no restriction at all on dimension, so it could be 2 or 3 or 4 or more dimensions; but the curvature in the sense of Lorentzian geometry is restricted to be $0$. So to make formal, mathematical sense out of this, you need to know something about Lorentzian geometry, a branch of the mathematical subject of differential geometry which is specialized for application to relativity.

Comment: Defining colloquial flatness in the first sentence, do you mean "without" rather than "with" curvature ?

Comment: Well, it's not a question of what I mean... within those quotation marks of my first sentence, you will find an exact quote taken from the OP.

Answer (score 8):

Space being flat essentially means that the laws of Euclidean geometry hold. The interior angles of a triangle sum to 180 degrees. Parallel geodesics (straight lines) never intersect, etc.

Consider, in contrast, the 2D surface of the earth, which is curved. You can start on the equator facing north, walk due north to the pole, turn 90 degrees, walk due south to the equator, turn 90 degrees, walk due west to your starting position, and turn 90 degrees to face north again. So that triangle in a curved space has 270 degrees, not just 180. And two nearby lines going north from the equator start out parallel but wind up intersecting at the pole. Such non-Euclidean things are not possible in flat space.

These same concepts can be generalize to spacetime. And in a theory of gravity where the equivalence principle holds you can represent tidal effects as curved spacetime.

Comment: I'll add to @Dale's excellent answer. He has given an example of  triangle whose angles add up to 270 degrees. It is possible to construct other triangles on the sphere whose angles add up to _different_ values, depending on the lengths of the sides: in a flat space the sum is independent of the length.

Comment: The lack of math gives this answer the widest applicability and the least redundancy.